# C# SqlException (0x80131904): Distributed transaction completed. Either enlist this session in a new transaction or the NULL transaction

Tags: c#, entity-framework, webforms, sqlexception, distributed-transactions

Stackers,  I am getting an exception `Distributed transaction completed. Either enlist this session in a new transaction or the NULL transaction` on the production server for my web application (Asp.Net Web Form with Telerik Controls + C# + SQL Database).
I have added the stack trace of the exception in the last.

The strange thing is the application is not using transactions for some of the processes where this exception occurred. And we have not implemented any kind of distributed system concepts.
Here is some information about the server where applications are hosted-

1. More than one instance of the same application are hosted on the same server. Means we have different clients and the same web application is hosted for each client on different public domain URLs.
2. Web Applications and their dedicated SQL database are on the same server.
3. All hosted web applications are using the same SQL user id to connect to their database.
4. Each application uses its own dedicated App Pool in the IIS.

**Can anyone help in this to figure out why I am getting this exception?
Any kind of help is appreciated :)**

> STACKTRACE:

```
Message: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.
Source: EntityFramework

at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.ObjectQueryExecutionPlan.Execute[TResultType](ObjectContext context, ObjectParameterCollection parameterValues)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClass7.b__5()
at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1..GetEnumerator>b__0()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
at System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
at Docktor2.DataAccess.Caching.InmatesCacheManager.GetInmate(Int32 inmateId)
at Docktor2.InmateMedicationManagement.InmateMedicationManagementControllerWithoutSession.get_CurrentInmate()
at Docktor2.InmateMedicationManagement.Presenters.InmateEncountersPresenter.SetCurrentInmateById(Int32 inmateId)
at Docktor2.InmateMedicationManagement.InmateDashBoard.InmateEncounters.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
at Docktor2.MasterPages.EncounterPage`1.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

INNEREXCEPTION:
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Distributed transaction completed. Either enlist this session in a new transaction or the NULL transaction.
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.InternalDispatcher`1.Dispatch[TTarget,TInterceptionContext,TResult](TTarget target, Func`3 operation, TInterceptionContext interceptionContext, Action`3 executing, Action`3 executed)
at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.Interception.DbCommandDispatcher.Reader(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext interceptionContext)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.Internal.EntityCommandDefinition.ExecuteStoreCommands(EntityCommand entityCommand, CommandBehavior behavior)
```

Comment: Is anything working?  It looks like error is in a stored procedure.  Did you check the SQL Server Logs (LDF file)?

Comment: @jdweng yes, almost everything is working in the system even the same process is working where we are getting the exception sometimes.
This means the exception is not continuous in the system for the same process.
And btw, there is no stored procedure used in the process.

Did not check the SQL server Logs, will check.

Comment: When it fails from cmd.exe >Netstat -a and check status of the connection.  When it fails I suspect you get a TIME_WAIT status.  This means the connection is half open and half close (a race condition).  TCP is robust where every message get an ACK.  When you close a connection you are suppose to get an ACK.  If both client and server attempt to close a connection at the same time one side doesn't get an ACK.  So Windows puts the connection in a TIME_WAIT state waiting forever for the ACK.  With TCP you should only close connection from client so you avoid this race condition.